# WAMP server is displaying "Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80"

Tags: wamp

My www folder has the necessary files, however, the error message seems to think otherwise. What might be the problem here? As you can see, www folder does have the login_page file, whereas, upon running localhost/ux2, I am getting the error "The requested URL /ux2/user/login_page was not found on this server."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, are you sure that your WAMP is working and online? you must get green Icon for Wamp on the start menu bar so you make sure that WAMP is working.
Secondly test WAMP by creating very basic html file like hello.html

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Heloo!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

if that test file worked, your login page should work.